# migration the shopping cart laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to build a shopping card and the reason is that all shopping cart are using session and i want save the data into my db with json.

now is that the right way to start.

migration

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('shopping_carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->json('soppingCart');
    $table->timestamps();
});
}
```

model

```
class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['shoppingCart'];

   protected $casts =['shoppingCart'  =>'json'];
}
```

Do i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your `migration` file :

```
...
$table->json('soppingCart');
...
```

`shoppingCart` instead of `soppingCart`.